# sum of squares in a list in one line?

Tags: python, list, sum

To demonstrate I have done sth.
This is my code do sum in three lines.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5];
sumOfList=0

for i in l:
    sumOfList+=i*i;
print sumOfList
```

I am curious can I do it in just one line?

Comment: You shouldn't use `sum` as a name for your variable for it shadows the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What about :

```
sum(map(lambda x:x*x,l))
```

we also use `reduce`:

```
print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y*y,l) # as pointed by @espang reduce(lambda x,y: x+y*y,l) is only ok, when the first value is 1 (because 1*1 == 1). The first value is not squared
```

We can take the first element, get its square, then add it to the head of the list so we can make sure that it's squared. Then we continue using reduce. It isn't worth all that work, as we have better alternatives.

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y*y,[l[:1][0]**2]+l[1:])
```

Just out of curiosity, I tried to compare the three solutions to sum the squares of `10000` numbers generated by `range`, and compute the execution time of every operation.

```
l=range(10000) 
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y*y,l)
print('using Reduce numbers: {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time))

from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
print sum(map(lambda x:x*x,l))
print('Sum after map square operation: {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time))

from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
print sum( i*i for i in l)
print('using list comprehension to sum: {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time))
```

Output:

Using `list comprehension` is faster

```
333283335000
using Reduce numbers: 0:00:00.003371
333283335000
Sum after map square operation: 0:00:00.002044
333283335000
using list comprehension to sum: 0:00:00.000916
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions  This is also equivalent to squares = map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)), but it’s more concise and readable.

Comment: reduce(lambda x,y: x+y*y,l) is only ok, when the first value is 1 (because 1*1 == 1). The first value is not squared

Comment: same result. List comprehension is fastest

Comment: @espang may be we can trick it by extracting the first element, get the square number and then add it to the rest of the list **reduce(lambda x,y: x+y*y,[l[:1][0]**2]+l[1:])** But it doesn't worth all that work as we have better alternatives

Comment: why this overly complex idea for such a simple thing.  it's not a list comprehension by the way it's a generator expression.

Comment: `reduce` takes an "initializer" argument which can be set to `0` like `reduce(operator.add, l, 0)` to get around the problem of squaring the first element of list `l`, however, `sum(i * i for i in l)` would be a better choice

Answer (score 30):

Yes, you can. Here it is using the `sum` function:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum(i*i for i in l))
```

Answer (score 16):

For bigger list and when performance matters you should use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = np.array(l)

np.sum(arr**2)
# or better:
np.dot(arr, arr)
```

Comment: at what size list should one consider using numpy over base python?

Comment: @baxx I compared sum(i*i for i in range(15)), with a=np.arange(15), np.dot(a,a). It was a tie (even after adding the time to include numpy as np! Any number larger than 15, and numpy is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function and use list comprehension

```
l = [2, 6, 10, 12, 16, 20]

def sumOfSquares(alist):
return ((sum([i**2 for i in alist]))-(sum(alist)**2)/len(alist))

print(sumOfSquares(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

sum(np.multiply(l,l))
```