# How can I code this for loop in a more concise way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with code as follows:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

my_list_average = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)

n = 0
for i in my_list:
    n += pow((my_list_average - i), 2)
```

What are the alternative ways of coding to calculate *n* without using *numpy* or *pandas* libraries functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of squares in a list in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894227/sum-of-squares-in-a-list-in-one-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum` with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
my_list_average = sum(my_list) / len(my_list)

n = sum(pow(my_list_average - i, 2) for i in my_list)
print(n)
```

**Output**

```
60.0
```