# index out of range question during recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am using python to try to get a sum of squares of the non-negative numbers of some tuples within a list:

```
lst1 = [(3, ('-5', '-4', '4')), (2, ('2', '4')), (3, ('-6', '4', '3'))]
```

so lst1 is my list where it has the first element being the tuple:
(3, ('-5', '-4', '4'))   # 3 is to indicate how many elements in this particular tuple

so I have a two functions, the first function (i.e. iterate) calculate the sum of squares of the non-negative number within a tuple. The second function (i.e. iterateList) would go through the list lst1, tuple-by-tuple, to calculate the sum of squares within each tuple, basically it calls the first function and then return a list where each element in the list being the sum of squares of each of the individual tuple since I build the list by concatenate them using the + in my iterateList function.

```
def iterate(lst, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return 0
    else:
        if (int (lst[start])) < 0:
            return iterate(lst, start+1, end)
        else:
            return (int(lst[start]))**2 + iterate(lst, start+1, end)

def iterateList(lst, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return
    else:
        print("value of start:", start)
        print(lst[start])
        print(lst[start][1])
        return [iterate(lst[start][1], 0, lst[start][0])] + iterateList(lst[start+1][1],
                                                                        0, lst[start+1][0])

lst1 = [(3, ('-5', '-4', '4')), (2, ('2', '4')), (3, ('-6', '4', '3'))]
```

However, I keep getting the error of index out of range:

[image]

I think it has to do with the second iteration inside the iterateList function. But I just not sure how to fix it or where the exact error is. I have added some print statement to check where the error is. It seems it happens to the second element within the list:
(2, ('2','4'))

but I just not sure what range it is talking about when the error says "index out of range".

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Right now you only show 2 function definitions and a list

Comment: Note: "*(3, ('-5', '-4', '4')) # 3 is to indicate how many elements in this particular tuple*". That's **bad design**, you can **use *len*** to find a sequence element count. Also what;s the expected result for that input list?

Comment: Use more `print` debugging (or even a proper debugger), so you can see how your values change. For example, you should check that's the actual input(s) to `iterate`, and what the actual return value of `iterate`. `print(f"{somevar = }")` can be helpful for that.

Comment: Is there any reason preventing you from computing the sum of squares like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894227 ?

Comment: `[sum(int(e1) ** 2 for e1 in e0[1] if int(e1) >= 0) for e0 in lst]` (will return `[16, 20, 25]`)? I don't know why the numbers in the tuples are actually strings. So we have many bad things here.

Comment: Also, it's very, very often not necessary and a bad design to iterate using indices in Python (and sometimes even impossible). Iterate directly on the list/tuple items: `for item in mylist: ...`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is on the return of iterateList function:

```
return [iterate(lst[start][1], 0, lst[start][0])] + iterateList(lst[start+1][1], 0,lst[start+1][0])
```

What is wrong:

1. List should remain the same (you should do lst, not lst[start+1][1])
2. You don't increase the index(you should do start +1, not 0)
3. You change the end index (you should do end, not lst[start+1][0])

So the correct way is:

```
return [iterate(lst[start][1], 0, lst[start][0])] + iterateList(lst, start+1, end)
```

Also return None will trigger an error, because you can not do list + Nonetype. You will have to change it with [].

Comment: hi, for some reasons your code doesn't work. It produces some error. Could you have a look again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the lengths of the tuples; they're just polluting your list of tuples and making everything more annoying to write.

When you do need to know the length of something, use [function `len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

Your numbers are stored as strings. There is no reason for that. Store them as actual numbers.

```py
lst2 = [tuple(map(int,t)) for _,t in lst1]
print(lst2)
#[(-5, -4, 4), (2, 4), (-6, 4, 3)]
```

When you need to calculate a sum, use [function `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). When you need to iterate on the elements of a tuple, use keyword `for`, either as a multiline [for-loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) or as a one-line [generator-expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).

```py
def sum_of_squares_of_positive(seq):
    return sum(x**2 for x in seq if x > 0)
```

When you need to build a list by applying a function to every element of a list, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or use [function `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```py
lst3 = list(map(sum_of_squares_of_positive, lst2))
print(lst3)
#[16, 20, 25]
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanations. But I am required to calculate sum not using for loop, while loop, or list, set comprehension. So that's why I use "recursion" here I think.

Comment: @hodondo Okay. Keep in mind though, that in some programming languages recursion and while-loops are equally good, but in some other programming languages, they are not. Unfortunately python is one of those languages. Recursion is terrible in python. And I do mean terrible, for many different reasons. Python is basically the worst language to learn recursion.

Comment: So when your teacher tells you to solve this problem in python but with recursion instead of for-loops, it's a bit as if your teacher told you to solve a problem with a hammer but using screws instead of nails. Screws can be as good as nails, just not when using a hammer.

Comment: @hodondo Although it's possible to use neither for-loops nor recursion: `def sum_of_squares_of_positive(seq): return sum(map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x>0, seq)))`

Comment: Oh thanks for the comments. Is my understanding correct that recursion in general and also here in my example would allow a stack to build up? so this takes up more memory than a non-recursive way at least in this example? thanks

Comment: @hodondo Yes that is correct. That is one of the reasons why recursion is often not a good idea in python. In most other languages it's possible to eliminate this stack under some circumstances, but not in python. And python has additional quirks that also make recursion not so good.